# Alignment of several items in a grid area

Tags: css, html, css-grid

I'm starting in web development. I have a problem where I want to place a time-line of twitter, facebook, embed youtube, etc. One below the other in a grid area. For some reason these are placed next to each other.

```css
.caja{
    display: grid;

    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 4fr 3fr 1fr;

    grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(4,6fr) 1.5fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row;


}
.caja .redes{
    grid-row: span 3;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
<div class ="redes">
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="600px" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/arkfgo?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by arkfgo</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9YffrCViTVk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they're next to each other because they both belong to `div.redes` which is placed in the first row and column, the elements you want to align must be direct children of the grid so just remove the `div.redes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the grid the right way, you will need to split the inside of your grid into div's. After you have done that, you can make separate rows and columns. I have made an example down below

```css
    .caja{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 4fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(4,6fr) 1.5fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;


}
.caja .redes{
  grid-row: span 3;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="caja">
    <div class ="redes">
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="600px" data-theme="dark" href="https://twitter.com/arkfgo?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by arkfgo</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
<div class ="redes">
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9YffrCViTVk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
    </div>
```

You can read more about grid layout on this side

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp